# Why Loki shows "timestamp too new" when i try to parse logs?

Tags: logging, timestamp, grafana-loki

**I've tried to parse custom logs. Loki not accept parsed timestamps cause:**

```
level=error ts=2020-09-18T07:17:52.655628313Z msg="final error sending batch" status=400 error="server returned HTTP status 400 Bad Request (400): entry for stream has timestamp too new: 2020-09-18 10:01:52.935 +0000 UTC"
```

But old logs with time, for example: 2020-09-09 10:01:52.935 or even 2020-09-17 10:01:52.935 loki parsing normally

My log:

```
2020-09-18 10:01:52.935;message
```

Steps to reproduce the behavior:
grafana/loki:latest
grafana/promtail:latest

My promtail config:

```
...
    scrape_configs:
  - job_name: myjob
    pipeline_stages:
    - regex:
        expression: '^(?P<timestamp>[\d-\s:.]{20,30});(?P<message>.*)'
    - timestamp:
        source: timestamp
        format: 2006-01-02 15:04:05.999
    static_configs:
    - targets:
        - localhost
      labels:
        job: myjob
        _path_: /logs/*log
```

My loki config:

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

ingester:
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
    final_sleep: 0s
  chunk_idle_period: 5m
  chunk_retain_period: 30s
  max_transfer_retries: 0

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2018-04-15
      store: boltdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 792h

storage_config:
  boltdb:
    directory: /tmp/loki/index

  filesystem:
    directory: /tmp/loki/chunks

limits_config:
  enforce_metric_name: false
  reject_old_samples: false

chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0s

table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: true
  retention_period: 792h
```

Comment: I'd guess it's related to the various other problems around the Unix timestamp reaching `1600000000`

Answer (score 1):

In promtail pipeline stage try this format:

```
pipeline_stages:
    - regex:
        expression: '^(?P<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\S\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d+\+\d{2}:\d{2}).*'
    - timestamp:
        source: timestamp
        format: RFC3339Nano
        action_on_failure: skip
```